# Which kind of mean (harmonic, geometric, arithmetic) is best suited for averaging probability ratios?

Tags: probability, mean, descriptive-statistics, ratio

There are a bunch of examples around on how harmonic mean is more suitable for averaging rates, e.g. speed (when the distance is fixed). But what about probability ratios (p(A)/p(B), i.e. how much more probable event A is compared to event B)?

If it makes any difference: In my model those ratios are always bigger than 1. Most are between 1 and 10, but in some cases the ratio is in the neighborhood of 1E+20.

Comment: I believe that the answer may be "it depends on the context and on how you feel the concept of average in your specific case". There exists a special branch within statistics called "ratio statistics" with these usual and some special indices of central tendency.

Comment: It depends, as ttnphns suggests on what kind of average is suited for your particular purpose. What's it *for*? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, the probabilities are for paths (sequences of states) in a markov model. The ratio is supposed how much more likely the Viterbi path is compared to another. So the ratio should always be 1 or higher.